# Civil datetime format to json with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got activities with a start and end date in my application which I parse to json and is collected by the frontend.

The datetime format is pretty shitty to convert(`2013-09-25T14:30:00.000Z`) in javascript however. Now I've read that you can use `DateTime.civil_from_format` somehow. I'm wondering, however, how I should implement that in my json building.

Since I'm quite the rails n00b I'm hoping that someone can help me out here.

**the rendering:**

`format.json {render json: @activities.to_json(:include => [:pictogram ,:users]) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a solution at the backend side, but that date is actually pretty easy to parse in Javascript:

`var d = new Date('2013-09-25T14:30:00.000Z')`

Use the JS Date methods like `d.toLocaleDateString()` to get a nicer date like `25-9-2013`.

Comment: **Edit: Fixed it by using `toLocaleString`**

On second thought; I see that it adds 2 hours to the string when using `d.toLocaleDateString() + d.toLocaleTimeString()`. Most likely because of the timezone. Is there a way to compensate it? Since the string shows 14:00:00 for example and the toLocaleTimeString() shows 16:00:00.